# Full Referrer dimension shows incorrect URLs in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, referrer

A lot of "Full Referrer" values are incorrect URLs in my Google Analytics reports:
[image]

For example, the first value should be "yandex.ru" or "yandex.com", not just "yandex" (because this is not actually a URL). 
**1. Why is Google Analytics showing non-URL values in this columns?

2. And is there any way to get the actual full referrer URL?**

Answer (score 1):

you should create a custom report and add to them:

- `page` (to see where traffic comes in)
- `source` (which provides only a domain of referrer)
- `referral path` (which is the full referrer url, but without domain)
- if interesting, add as a metric `pageviews`

[image]

After you build it up, export it and merge columns with source and referral path to get full referrer urls.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Evgeniy. I created the exact custom report you suggested, but "source" dimension didn't contain the full domain for me. If domain is "website.com", most sources just contain the text "website": https://i.gyazo.com/7e763ebd774a207bbff70b4424b669a9.png